# How to find declaration of string resource in Android project using Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, string, android-resources

When I use Android Studio, I can right-click on a string resource variable and choose Goto->Declaration in order to open the XML string resource file where it is defined.  When I try to "open declaration" using Eclipse ADT, it opens the "R" file instead.

How can I get Eclipse ADT to do the same behavior as Android Studio?

Comment: I think ADT doesn't include this feature. Would be happy to be proven wrong though :)

Comment: Maybe someone should make a plug-in for that!

Comment: How about a +1 for my question? lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control-click on the variable and it should then open a popup menu with the XML file(s) where the resource is defined.

Just select the desired XML file and voila.

Comment: I didn't know this existed! +1 to both question and answer :)